# Online configuration of a server

Tags: linux, report, pentaho

I am trying to setup pentaho like following on my online server:

http://demo.pentaho.com/pentaho/Home

I want to run reports on my online web-server (to make report accessible round the globe), so I uploaded Pentaho-BI-Server to my domain. Users of the report-designer usually publish to a BI-server to let their reports run on the web. I am not able to figure out how can I configure it, because the documentation help is not vivid for setting up the Pentaho as an online server. Kindly let me know how can I do that?

Is there any tutorial available? Any help would be really appreciated.

- BI-Server: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pent.../4.8.0-stable/
- Documentation for the BI-Server: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Serv...+Documentation

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of **your own** earlier question: [Migrate local setup to online server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535276/migrate-local-setup-to-online-server). Note that it's better to edit that question (it'll bump it if the edit's substantial), or use [another way to draw attention (with a bounty)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions).

Comment: In addition, [reporting-services] is not a generic term/tag, it's another tool by MS for reporting.

Comment: @Jeroen okay thanks, Can you help regaring this question, have you ever used pentaho?

Comment: No, sorry, I have a look at the [reporting-services] tag once in a while, which is why I saw your question. I have no experience with [pentaho].

Comment: @Jeroen okay thanks. Its help is not very common on internet :(

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow? SO is filled with friendly folks trying to help. I think you may be getting low response because your question is a tutorial request, typically questions with a bit of source code are preferred. In addition, try asking yourself [these questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), they would help you improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tutorials available online, more or less up to date. A quick search on Google reveals the following:

http://kirk.webfinish.com/2012/06/how-to-configure-pentaho-bi-server-ce-manual-with-postgresql-9-1/
http://interestingittips.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/complete-pentaho-installation-on-ubuntu-part-1/

It should be pretty straight forward. Download, uncompress, setup and run. Maybe a more specific questions can bring more detailed answers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I ran patenho on my localhost successfully but i am having problem with setting it up online usually for online setup you know in wordpress or the like all we need to do is to uncompress and on the page give required info and DONE! . But its not tht simple in terms of patenho and no direct help is available so far

Comment: Please note that Pentaho is composed of different tools. The one you mentioned in the other question is the Report Editor, not the BI server.

Comment: This question is about BI-server not the reporting tool, Because Users of the report-designer usually publish to a BI-server to let their reports run on the web.

Comment: Understood, I wanted to be clear, because indeed, the biserver-ce is pretty much uncompress, set up a few files and done.